# Converting Raster to Vector, Google Earth Engine,

Tags: google-earth-engine, vectorization

By running the code, one obtains:

`FeatureCollection (Error) Image.reduceToVectors: First band ('x') of image must be integral.`

I don´t understand this error. My goal is to convert the pixel values into vector data, e.g. Points.

`var coorsfeat = mean.reduceToVectors({
  reducer : null,
  geometry : geometry,
  crs :mean.projection().getInfo().crs,
  crsTransform :mean.projection().getInfo().transform,
  geometryType : 'centroid',
  labelProperty : 'Precip'
})`

[Link to GEE](https://code.earthengine.google.com/512f59ae345f5513fec72d1ee4959959)

Comment: Using different data, or another Type of Geometry(points) to reduce over, did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error regarding the Integral was fixable by converting the input Data from float to Int. I recommend a multiplication to evade Data precision loss.

Fix:
`var mean= ImCol.filterBounds(aoi).filterDate('2017-01-01','2017-12-31').mean()
.multiply(10000).toInt()`

Unfortunately, this retrieves 0 Features.

Changing the Following Arguments to `scale` did the Trick :

`crs :mean.projection().getInfo().crs,
 crsTransform :mean.projection().getInfo().transform`

Unfortunately, this doesn't obtain one Feature per Pixel. Gonna open a new Thread for this one, as it seems to be a different problem then initially described in this thread

Comment: did you open that thread? can you share it here?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313926/converting-each-rastercell-to-its-own-point-vector-google-earth-engine