# Converting each Rastercell to its own Point-Vector, Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, vectorization

[Related Post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313799/converting-raster-to-vector-google-earth-engine)

My **goal** is to perfectly obtain **one vector point per raster cell**, located at the Center of the RasterCell
Running `.reduceToVectors()` with the `scale` argument retrieves vector points, but none fit the raster.

`var coorsfeat = mean.reduceToVectors({
  reducer : null,
  geometry : geometry,
  scale:6800,
  //crs :mean.projection().getInfo().crs,
  //crsTransform :mean.projection().getInfo().transform,
  geometryType : 'centroid',
  labelProperty : 'Precip',
  eightConnected: false
})`

[image]

Running with:

`scale: mean.projection().nominalScale().getInfo()` = `111319.49079327357` retrieves **no features**

Running with :

`crs :mean.projection().getInfo().crs,
 crsTransform :mean.projection().getInfo().transform,`

retrieves **no Features**

Is there a more elegant way of achieving the goal?

[Link to GEE](https://code.earthengine.google.com/ea934cf7030d8b3241259c84b824aa34)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loosely based on [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293109/how-to-to-extract-coordinates-of-pixels-inside-a-polygon-in-google-earth-engine/293140#293140), you can make a feature collection consisting of points at the center of each pixel.

For your purpose, you can do that as follows:

```
// get the projection of the first image
var projection = ImCol.filterBounds(geometry).filterDate('2017-01-01','2017-12-31').first().projection();

function spacedPoints(AOI, projection) {
  // make a coordinate image
  // get coordinates image
  var latlon = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().reproject(projection);
  // put each lon lat in a list 
  var coords = latlon.select(['longitude', 'latitude'])
                 .reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
                                geometry: AOI,
                                scale: projection.nominalScale().toInt(),
                                maxPixels: 10e10
  });
  // zip the coordinates for representation. Example: zip([1, 3],[2, 4]) --> [[1, 2], [3,4]]
  var point_list = ee.List(coords.get('longitude')).zip(ee.List(coords.get('latitude')));
  // preset a random list
  var list = ee.List([0]);
  // map over the point list and add features as geometry
    var feats = ee.FeatureCollection(point_list.map(function(point){
      var ind = point_list.indexOf(point);
      var feat = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(point_list.get(ind)), {'ID': ind});
    return list.add(feat);
    }).flatten().removeAll([0]));

  return feats;
}

// apply the function
var output = spacedPoints(geometry, projection); print(output)
Map.addLayer(output, {color: 'green'})
```

[link script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/628cff9711d23beb520169a0ba0cdbe4)