# How to convert a raster to point with certain value GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to convert the raster to point where hough band have 1 value. I tried with bellow code but can't get the output. any way to get the latlon of the pixels where the value is 1? Please help me. [This post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313926/converting-each-rastercell-to-its-own-point-vector-google-earth-engine/365703?noredirect=1#comment598505_365703)

```
var img = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
            .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-02-01', '2020-02-28'))
            .filterBounds(area)
            .select(["VH"])
var mome = img.min()
var areac = mome
var canny = ee.Algorithms.CannyEdgeDetector({
  image: filt, threshold: 0.2, sigma: 4.5
});
var hough = ee.Algorithms.HoughTransform(canny, 256, 2, 10).eq(1).clip(area); //this 
is an binary image.

var proj = hough.projection()
var latlon = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().reproject(proj)
var coords = if(hough.select("band")==1){
                  latlon.select(['longitude', 'latitude']).reduceRegion({
                               reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
                               geometry: area,
                               scale: 50,
                                })
               }
var lat = ee.List(coords.get('latitude'))
var lon = ee.List(coords.get('longitude'))
var point_list = lon.zip(lat)
var mp = ee.Geometry.MultiPoint(point_list)
Map.addLayer(mp,{}, 'Points')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a pixel lat lon image and mask all values where hough is not one. Than apply reduce region and continue the code you had. javaScript `If` does not work on server-side variables. Bassically, the `updateMask` does the job.

```
// make lat and lon image
var latlon = ee.Image.pixelLonLat();
// mask all values where hough is zero
var latlonMasked = latlon.updateMask(hough.eq(1))
// get the lat and lon values to a list
var coords = latlonMasked.reduceRegion({
                               reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
                               geometry: area,
                               scale: 50,
                                })
```

I made an example geometry and deleted some unnecessary code lines (`reproject()`, `clip()`). [Link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/33d7960d0776b8be0970ca7d7e3f101f)